# Yammer authentication

Tags: yammer

I have registered a dummy app with Yammer, as I am still in testing phase. I gave the homepage of my org as the redirect URI. Honestly, there is no app hosted anywhere. Still, I think it is possible to test the authentication and go till creating a token. This is what I have done.

1. Navigated to https://www.yammer.com/client_applications page.
2. Registered an application. I provided the "RedirectURI". I got a "Client Id", "Client Secret", and "Expected Re-direct".

Since I don't have an app to launch anything from, I manually typed in the following URL in the browser. "https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[:client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]".

3. I was taken to the app registration page. I clicked "Allow".
4. Now the page is redirected to the home page of my org, as I provided along with "www.<<>>.com/code=".
5. I copied this code over, tried to launch "https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&code=%s".
6. I expected a token to be created, so that I go back to my dummy JAVA program and start connecting to Yammer, but I am not allowed to connect in above step. I am getting a "Not Authorised" error.

Can some please point out what I need to do? My requirement is that I get this token not from with in an app, but then on use it in a SWT based Rich Client JAVA application to connect to Yammer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the request to oauth2/access_token.json needs to be a POST not a GET